# How to delete SQL Local Db instance if user owner has been deleted?

Tags: sql-server, localdb

I have a strange situation where a user on this workstation was deleted, but they owned a shared localdb. I now need to clean up this mess as this shared database is used by an automated system test, but I can't delete it.

If I do `sqllocaldb i TheDatabase` I get something similar to:

```
Invalid SID or account name (domain\account): "S-1-12-1-3936653584-1214288953-3252656789-1065815451".
Name:               TheDatabase
Shared name:        TheDatabase
Owner:              S-1-12-1-3936653584-1214288953-3252656789-1065815451
Instance pipe name: np:\\.\pipe\LOCALDB#SH77646D\tsql\query
```

If I try to delete this database I get:

```
Delete of LocalDB instance ".\TheDatabase" failed because of the following error:
API caller is not LocalDB instance owner.
```

How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 3):

When running as an admin it seems I was able to unshare it with:

```
sqllocaldb u .\TheDatabase
```

From there I was able to delete it.